# Navigation submenu - appear to left if window is too narrow

Tags: html, css

I want a submenu to appear to the left of the main menu if the window width is less than 1086px. I'm using this bit of code to make that happen, but it's not working. I have the background set to red just to show when the max-width is being reached. If the background is changing to red, why isn't the `right: 100%` seem to be doing anything?

```
@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-subcontent {
    right: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
right: 180px;
}

.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdownsub {
  position: absolute;
  display: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 180px;
}

.dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 180px;
  background: orange;
}

@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-subcontent {
  right: 100%;
 background: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownsub:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Accounts Receivable</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#cccccc">
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='dropbtn'>MENU<i class='fas fa-chevron-down'></i></button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
      <a href='#'>Option 1</a>
      <div class='dropdown2'>
        <a href='#'>Submenu ></a>
        <div class='dropdown-subcontent'>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 1</a>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 2</a>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href='#'>Option 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you search is

```
@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-subcontent {
    left: -100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

`right: 100%;` is the same as `left: 0;`

Check, how your DIV's are nested and how their position is depending on their parent element.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
right: 180px;
}

.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdownsub {
  position: absolute;
  display: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 180px;
}

.dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 180px;
  background: orange;
}

@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-subcontent {
  left: -100%;
 background: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownsub:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Accounts Receivable</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#cccccc">
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='dropbtn'>MENU<i class='fas fa-chevron-down'></i></button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
      <a href='#'>Option 1</a>
      <div class='dropdown2'>
        <a href='#'>Submenu ></a>
        <div class='dropdown-subcontent'>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 1</a>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 2</a>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href='#'>Option 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```